# How to configure the ITfoxtec sample application "TestWebAppCore" with Azure AD as IdP

Tags: azure, saml-2.0

I'm trying to adapt the configuration of the ITfoxtec sample application TestWebAppCore from
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCore
to use a SAML-configured Enterprise Application on Azure AD.

In appsettings.json I configured "IdPMetadata" with the metadata URL for the Enterrise Application in Azure AD, of this kind: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9...3/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=c..."

and I have not changed the other lines:

```
"SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
"SigningCertificateFile": "itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebappcore_Certificate.pfx",
"SigningCertificatePassword": "!QAZ2wsx",

//"SignatureValidationCertificateFile": "xxx.cer",
"CertificateValidationMode": "None", // "ChainTrust"
"RevocationMode": "NoCheck"
```

What are the "right" configuration that must be applied in the sample web app and on the Azure AD SAML configuration panel "Azure AD-side" ? In Azure AD SAML specially for the configuration items:

Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL), I tried "https://localhost:44306/"
and
Sign on URL: I tried "https://localhost:44306/Auth/AssertionConsumerService"

but also after a "Login" (with my Azure credentials) the "users Claims" are not visible in the Home Page of the web application.

Thanks all.

Comment: have you configured the SAML attributes in the Azure app?

Answer (score 0):

Now I have fixed my implementation of the "TestWebAppCore" sample in ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.

These are the settings in the Azure AD administration console:

- Identifier (Entity ID): itfoxtec-testwebappcore
- Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL):
  https://localhost:44306/Auth/AssertionConsumerService
- Sign on URL, Relay State and Logout Url not configured.

And these are the configurations in appsettings.json:

```
"Saml2": {
"IdPMetadata": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9...3/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=c...8",

"Issuer": "itfoxtec-testwebappcore",

"SingleSignOnDestination": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9...3/saml2",

"SingleLogoutDestination": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9...3/saml2",

"SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
"SigningCertificateFile": "itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebappcore_Certificate.pfx",
"SigningCertificatePassword": "!QAZ2wsx",

"CertificateValidationMode": "None", // "ChainTrust"
"RevocationMode": "NoCheck"
```

}

I compiled with .NET 5.0.
Note that in AuthController.cs I have commented the line

```
NameIdPolicy = new NameIdPolicy { AllowCreate = true, Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" },
```

otherwise the user name presented in the "Secure" page is an ID (in "persistent" format) and not the username with email. As an alternative it is possible to change the line with this one:

```
NameIdPolicy = new NameIdPolicy { AllowCreate = true, Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" },
```

Another good example that use the same ITfoxtex SAML identity library is this one:
https://github.com/nickgamb/Okta_SAML_Example (see also the article https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp).